# Xcode 11.4 issue: Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Code was working in  Xcode 11.3 but after updating to 11.4, I am now getting two errors:

> Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator.
>
> Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type UpdateTagView found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for UpdateTagView may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

This is how I add the Objects to the Environment:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy

        let em = EventManager()
        let tagger = UpdateTagView()

        let contentView = ContentView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
            .environmentObject(em)
            .environmentObject(tagger)

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

I call them inside the View with @EnvironmentObject:

```
struct ViewName: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var em: EventManager
    @EnvironmentObject var tagger: UpdateTagView
```

Here is an example of what is in the ObservableObject:

```
class UpdateTagView: ObservableObject {

    @Published var counter: Int = 0
    @Published var language: String = "English"

}
```

Cheers~

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 11.4 (11E146) with just created project and your code added. It seems it is due to different code.

Comment: I tried this code on two different laptops, works on Xcode 11.3 but not 11.4.
I tried a previous version of the project on Xcode 11.4 and it had the same errors.

Thanks for checking though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed exactly the same issue when compiling our app in Release configuration. In Xcode 11.3 it worked but when we moved to Xcode 11.4 it stopped with exactly the same crash (@EnvironmentObject was not propagated in the hierarchy)

It looks like a bug in Swift compiler in metadata stripping algorithm. Temporarily you can either switch configuration to debug or manually switch `Reflection Metadata Level` (in your target Build Settings) from `None` to `Without Names`.